# Property X doesn't exist on type Y[]

Tags: angular, typescript

**I'm getting that error:**

> questions does not exist on type 'Quiz[]'

**This is my model**

```
export interface Quiz {
$key ?: string;
categorie ?: string;

questions : Questions[]
}

export interface Questions {

id ?: number;
question ?: string;
answer?: string;

}
```

**And this is my code**

```
import {Quiz} from "../models/quiz";

export class ProfComponent {

quiz = [] as  Quiz[];


nextQuestion(quiz) {

    this.quiz.questions.push(quiz.questions)
}


}
```

I can't push data into **quiz.questions**

what could be wrong?

Comment: async nextQuestion(quiz)   {
    await this.quiz.push(quiz)
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring `quiz` property as array via `Quiz[]`, therefore you need to access item of array to be able to access `questions` property.

But you probably want to redeclare the property to just `Quiz`...

Also you need to instantiate the `questions` array first to be able to call `push` on it.

```
import {Quiz} from "../models/quiz";

export class ProfComponent {

  quiz = {questions: []} as Quiz;

  nextQuestion(quiz) {
    this.quiz.questions.push(quiz.questions)
  }

}
```

Or if you want to have array of quizes, do it like this:

```
import {Quiz} from "../models/quiz";

export class ProfComponent {

  quizes = [{questions: []}] as Quiz[]; // array of Quiz objects

  nextQuestion(quiz) {
    this.quizes[0].questions.push(quiz.questions); // access the first quiz
  }

}
```

Comment: But if i want the **quiz** variable to be a array how could I do that ??

Comment: Then you need to have some quiz instance in that array. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Before pushing values , you need to initialize the array,

```
nextQuestion(quiz) {
     this.quiz.questions = [];
    this.quiz.questions.push(quiz.questions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
quiz = new Quiz();
```

or

```
this.quiz[0].questions.push(quiz.questions)
```

When you initialize `quiz` as array, you need to address a specific array entry to get an actual `Quiz`, or you don't make it an array if that is not the intention

Comment: I want to store several **quizs** into Quiz[] so i need this array , i tried your solution but i get the error **this.quiz[0].questions.push is not a function**

Comment: There needs to be a `Quiz` first in `this.quiz[0]`. Perhaps a `this.quiz.push(new Quiz());` before the `this.quiz[0].questions.push(quiz.questions);`

Comment: I forget to mention that I already succeced to to push the first data in my array but i can't access to the variable **this.quiz.questions** to push more questions I don't know why !

Comment: "I already succeced to to push the first data" Can you please add the code to your question that shows how you do that?

Comment: async nextQuestion(quiz) { await this.quiz.push(quiz) }

Comment: `await` in `await this.quiz.push(quiz)` doesn't make sense. `await this.quiz.push(quiz)` is not an async operation.